# Firebase indexOn warning for dynamic values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here are my Firebase database structure and my query.

[image]

And my query on this structure is:

```
var messageRef = databaseRef.child(`/messagesThread/-KdzCvVW5icW7ZuSIAxV`);

messageRef.orderByChild(`/readBy/{userId}`).equalTo(false).on("child_added", (snapshots)=>{
  console.log("Unread messages = " + snapshots.numChildren());
});
```

But above query giving me warning as

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "readBy/{userId}".
```

So how to add this indexOn with dynamic `{userId}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since indexing on a wildcard is not great, you can modify the structure and then index:

```
---readBy-+
          |
           294jjfouurjkfJDGLS+
                             |
                            isRead: true
```

Now you can add to the security rules:

```
"readBy": {
  ".indexOn": "isRead"
}
```

Comment: Yup. Also see my answer here for a longer explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value